# cURL doesn't save the cookie inside a k8s cronjob

Tags: curl, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I want to create a cronjob that interacts with my API.
First, I need to send a request to authentificate, then send a GET request

Here is the yaml of my cronjob:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: verification-pointage
  namespace: isi-incubator
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: verification-pointage
              image: curlimages/curl:7.77.0
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
              args: ["curl -c session -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -d '{\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"password\":\"johndoe123\"}' http://odoo-api/authentication  && curl -b session http://odoo-api/timesheets/verification"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

When I do the two curl commands in local, I have no problem, but when the commands are executed in the cronjob, the `session` doesn't seem to have been created. So the second command cannot use the cookie stored in the session file.

Comment: Since you mentioned about "When I do the two curl commands in local, ", did you try those commands in docker/kubernetes jobs? or just executed them in shell? Also regarding your fix, it is related to a readonly filesystem? If you can share more info that will help the next user.

Comment: I just executed the two curl commands in local shell.
I imagine that the default folder is in read-only, so I moved the session file to the `tmp` folder, which seems to allow write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I change the path to the cookie file from `session` to `tmp/session` and it works